# Tweaking a third party Javascript script that is running on my Shopify store

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, input, shopify

Hi I have an online store on Shopify that uses a custom app to implement a calculator as my products are sold by the square metre. From what I can tell, the way the app works is it generates a new product variant depending on the dimensions given, then adds this new variant to the cart when required.

The app calculator is working well but it has a few annoyances that I am trying to sort. I have no access to edit the JS file as it is stored on the app creator's website.

The main problem I have is that the calculator only calculates one the user clicks **off** the numeric input box. I want it to work whenever there is a change to the input box. I have narrowed this down to there being a **onfocusout="onChange(null)"** inside the  tag. I need to change this to **oninput="onChange(null)"** but as I have no access to edit the JS file I cannot figure out how to do this.

The JS file is loaded using async, I'm not sure what this means. Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Many thanks
Jon

Comment: Is the private APP is built for your store only or developed by any 3rd party provider?

Comment: Are you paying for it or free to use?

Comment: I'm paying for it, but the developer said they are looking into it but I'm not holding out much hope

Comment: I have come up with a workaround but it's a bit messy - 

I have written a Javascript script that loads on body onLoad which adds an EventListener to the input box. The problem is that the script for the calculator does not load immediately, so I've had to delay my onLoad script by 3 seconds for it to work. Not ideal, but does work.

Comment: you need to run code on window load and wait until the script is loaded or developed a logic to check for JS code until the same is added to the website. and then trigger the own code.